# Module "XXXXX" is not installed qt/qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a line of code in cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<**CppClass**>("MyLibrary", 1, 0, "QmlContainer");
```

But when I try to `import MyLibrary 1.0` in a QML file, I get this error:

> `MyLibrary` is not installed

Can someone help me here with the missing link?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `CppClass`?

Comment: CppClass is my user defined class

Comment: Right. Did you try to run qmake i.e. `Build > Run qmake` and build?

Comment: Would help to see your entire main.cpp file.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I just created the instance of a the class right after "QQmlApplicationEngine engine;" in main.cpp file. Earlier I was creating the class instance just before "return app.exec();"

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I am having difficulty in sharing main.cpp file